# How to find an object's target scope with statement `global`?

Tags: python, scope, global

Today I'm playing with my toy object.
Through which I found something weird about `global` statement.
Here is my code inside `magic_z.py`

```
class MagicBall(object):
    def __del__(self):
        global _cat
        _cat = self
        print "Cat has 9 lives"

m = MagicBall()
```

And here comes the experiments:

```
In [1]: from magic_z import *

In [2]: m.__module__
Out[2]: 'magic_z'

In [3]: import magic_z

In [4]: del m

In [5]: _cat
NameError: name '_cat' is not defined

In [6]: magic_z._cat
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_cat'

In [7]: m2 = magic_z.MagicBall()

In [8]: del m2
Cat has 9 lives

In [9]: _cat
NameError: name '_cat' is not defined

In [10]: magic_z._cat
Out[10]: <magic_z.MagicBall at 0x102eff590>

In [11]: m3 = MagicBall()

In [12]: del m3
Cat has 9 lives

In [13]: _cat
NameError: name '_cat' is not defined

In [14]: m3 = MagicBall()

In [15]: m3.__module__
Out[15]: 'magic_z'

In [16]: magic_z._cat
Out[16]: <magic_z.MagicBall at 0x102e61b50>
```

It seems that `global` will update variables to the global scope of the `target_object.__module__` refers to.
But why nothing happened when I delete the first `m` object created by command `[1]`?
I mean how did python know that the `magic_z` object imported by command `[3]` wasn't the target of `global` statement in object `m`?
Since `m3` and `m`'s `__module__` attribute value both are `"magic_z"`?
And why the `m3` object created by `MagicBall` imported from command `[1]` can trigger the `__del__` function correctly and change the `_cat` attribute of `magic_z` object?

---

Version: `python 2.7.6` & `IPython 3.2.1`

Comment: I don't get the `NameError` on Python 2.7.9 IDLE. It might be specific to your IDE?

Comment: The NameError on which line number? I tried this in ordinary python(2.7.6) shell again, it raised NameError on line 5.

Answer (score 1):

`del x` doesn't necessarily destruct the object referenced by `x`. It only removes the reference. The object is destructed when there are no more references to it.

The object `m` has two references to it: one in the `magic_z` module, and one in the main module (created when you imported `*`). `del m` in the main module only deletes one of those, so the object is still alive and `__del__` isn't called.

To get the object's `__del__` to be called, you'd need to also `del magic_z.m`.

`m2` and `m3` had only one reference, so deleting that reference caused the object to be destructed -- although that destruction was canceled by your creating a new reference inside `__del__`.

Note also that IPython can hold references to objects which were returned by your commands. For example, a reference is held to the `_cat` object in `Out[10]`, which is why it isn't destructed later when `_cat` is overwritten. If this reference wasn't held, the program would behave differently - possibly an infinite loop.

Comment: I did `del magic_z.m; del m` with your advice, but the magic method still wasn't triggered. And,  does `global` statement actually targets `obj.__module__` as I guessed?

Comment: @Zen Maybe there was another reference held somewhere (e.g. by IPython) at that point. And `global` targets the module that the function was defined in.

Comment: things became weirder when I used the primitive python interactive shell. After `del magic_z.m; del m`, nothing happened, but after I executed `vars()` on global scope, the `__del__` method of `m` was triggered! What happened?

Comment: @Zen The normal shell holds the last output in the variable `_`. I guess it had a reference to `m`, and when you evaluated something else it was released.